# What is the dressing criteria for women while offering Prayers?

Tags: salat, women, awrah

Which type of dress a women can wear while offering prayer.I just want to know that is tied is allowed while offering Prayers.

Answer (score 1):

The *satar* must be covered during prayer. For women this is the entire body except face and hands. The cloth must be thick enough that the colour of the skin is not apparent through it.

The evidence for covering the satar during prayer is:

> خذوا زينتكم عند كل مسجد
>
> take your adornment at every mosque
>
> <sup>— [Quran 7:31](http://quran.com/7/31)</sup>

> لا يقبل الله صلاة حائض إلا بخمار
>
> Salat of a women who has reached the age of menstruation is not accepted without a Khimar
>
> <sup>— [Tirmizi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/229) , [Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1306980) etc.</sup>